# Calling java generic function from scala

Tags: scala, generics

I am new to scala and am having an issue in calling a "generic" function in the java NIO library (from scala 2.10.x).  Reducing the code to a simple test:

```
import java.net._
import java.nio.channels.{MembershipKey, DatagramChannel}

object Test {
  val channel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
    .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
    ...
}
```

This results in:

```
Error:(40, 48) type mismatch;
 found   : java.net.SocketOption[Boolean]
 required: java.net.SocketOption[Any]
Note: Boolean <: Any, but Java-defined trait SocketOption is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
  channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                                           ^
```

I assume there is some way to resolve this without resorting to writing a wrapper in java.  Have tried recasting in a variety of ways without success.

Question: how do I resolve the above?

Answer (score 7):

Method `setOption` is polymorphic

```
setOption[T](name: SocketOption[T], value: T): DatagramChannel
```

so when calling

```
setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
```

scala see that types of arguments are slightly different

```
StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR: SocketOption[java.lang.Boolean]
true: scala.Boolean
```

and compiler tries to narrow `T` to the most common type between `java.lang.Boolean <: AnyRef` and `scala.Boolean <: AnyVal` which is `Any`

to fix this issue, you need to either provide explicit type for `setOption`

```
setOption[java.lang.Boolean](StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
```

or use type ascription (then `T` will be inferred correctly)

```
setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true: java.lang.Boolean)
```